# pagespeed results: time gap in waterfall. Why?

Tags: pagespeed, waterfall

Just a curiosity I'd like to understand. When I do a pagespeed test (gmetrix), there's one fairly large time gap between items. I'm not sure why that is, or if there's a quick fix, but would like to be more enlightened on the subject. Here's a screenshot:

[image: gap in waterfall timeline]

Anyone understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Without the URL there is not much I can help you with.

The most likely reason is because of the font file, font-awesome.tff.  Fonts are considered CSS and the Browser cannot render until all CSS is loaded in the DOM.

When the Browser saw the font file it said, oh no! got to start over again!
That's a lot of work and would stall the retrieval of page resources.

Font not so awesome.